# Maximum value of $\lambda$ in polynomial expression.

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x),g(x),h(x),\phi(x)$ are polynomial in $x$  and
>
> $\displaystyle \bigg(\int^{x}_{1}f(x)\cdot h(x)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int^{x}_{1}g(x)\cdot \phi(x)dx\bigg)-\bigg(\int^{x}_{1}f(x)\cdot \phi(x)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int^{x}_{1}g(x)\cdot h(x)dx\bigg),$
>
> is divisible by $(x-1)^{\lambda}.$ Then maximum value of $\lambda$ is

Trial for Solution: Let

$f(x)=F\; , g(x)=G\; , h(x)=H\;,\phi(x)=P$

So we have $$K'(x)=(F\cdot H)\int^{x}_{1}G\cdot Pdx+(G\cdot P)\int^{x}_{1}G\cdot Pdx-F\cdot P\int^{x}_{1}G\cdot Hdx-G\cdot H\int^{x}_{1}F\cdot Pdx$$

$$K''(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(F\cdot H)\int^{x}_{1}G\cdot Pdx +\frac{d}{dx}(G\cdot P)\int^{x}_{1}G\cdot Pdx-\frac{d}{dx}(F\cdot P)\int^{x}_{1}G\cdot Hdx-\frac{d}{dx}(G\cdot H)\int^{x}_{1}F\cdot Pdx$$

Could some helo me how to solve from here, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that $f(x),g(x),h(x),\phi(x)$ are polynomials with degree $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$. You have:

$$f(x)\cdot h(x) = \Bigg( \sum_{i=0}^{n_1}a_iu^i \Bigg)\Bigg( \sum_{i=0}^{n_3}b_iu^i \Bigg) = \Bigg( \sum_{i=0}^{n_1+n_3}c_iu^i \Bigg) $$

Therefore:

$$\int^{x}_{1}f(x)\cdot h(x)dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n_1+n_3}c'_i x^{i+1} = \sum_{j=1}^{n_1+n_3+1}c'_{j+1}x^{j} $$

Doing this for the rest of the integrals you will have two summatory that can be converged into one adjusting the $c'_i-c''_i= c'''_j$. After this you'll have the upper bound of summation and the max $\lambda$ in function of the $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$.

Note that: $$ (x-1)^\lambda = \sum_{i=0}^\lambda {{\lambda}\choose{i}} x^i(-1)^{\lambda-k} = \sum_{i=0}^\lambda d_ix^i  $$